# Construtor esta vindo vazio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estou fazendo um programa em asp net web apllication, porem quando tento comunicar a controller com a service o construtor esta saind nulo, as dependencias ja estão configuradas no projeto.

```
public HomeController(){}
public readonly OficinaService _oficinaService;

public HomeController(OficinaService oficinaService)
{
    this._oficinaService = oficinaService;


}
```

segue a baixo o projeto no gitHub
https://github.com/REIFERREIRA/ProjHi

Comment: Apenas como observação, vi que o seu service tem um construtor recebendo o controller como parâmetro, e o controller recebe o service como parâmetro no seu construtor. Acredito que essa redundância não esteja correta. Também não cheguei a ver (posso não ter percebido) qualquer configuração de injeção de dependência no projeto...

Answer (score 0):

Remova o construtor vazio da sua controller:

```
public HomeController(){}
```

> Quando a Injeção de Dependência é aplicada corretamente,
>   é importante que cada tipo tenha apenas um construtor -
>   vários construtores são redundantes, tornam sua configuração DI frágil
>   e levam a problemas de capacidade de manutenção.

Referência:

- https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2013/di-anti-pattern-multiple-constructors/

Comment: Não funciona, se eu remover o public HomeController(){}, da o seguinte erro: Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.Estou meio sem saída já tentei de tudo.

Comment: @GABRIELVFA você registrou o DI? Qual framework está usando? Não encontrei no seu projeto.